# Error when retrieving value from database and applying to anchor tag.

Tags: php, syntax, tags, anchor

I want to give  link to the retrieved value from database but the error is coming for the below code:

```
Print " <td>" "<a href="#">".$info['shopname'] ."</a>" "</td> ";
```

as

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14

So please rectify it how to apply multiple html tags in print statement

Comment: Print “ <td>” “<a href=”#“>”.$info['shopname'] .“</a>” “</td> ”;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
 echo  " <td><a href='#'>".$info['shopname'] ."</a></td>";
```

OR

```
print  " <td><a href='#'>".$info['shopname'] ."</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing concatenation operators (actually you're using strings incorrectly):

```
Print " <td>" "<a href="#">".$info['shopname'] ."</a>" "</td> ";
```

should be:

```
Print " <td>" . "<a href=\"#\">".$info['shopname'] ."</a>". "</td> ";
```

or even better:

```
Print " <td><a href=\"#\">".$info['shopname'] ."</a></td> ";
```

or even more betterer:

```
Print ' <td><a href="#">'.$info['shopname'] .'</a></td> ';
```

or even more bettererer:

```
printf(' <td><a href="#">%s</a></td> ', $info['shopname']);
```

Comment: or Print "<td><a href=\"#\">{$info['shopname']}</a></td>";

Answer (score 0):

```
Print " <td>" "<a href="#">".$info['shopname'] ."</a>" "</td> ";
```

should be

```
print " <td> <a href='#'>".$info['shopname'] ."</a> </td> ";
```