# Please rectify this syntax error echo "<td> <a href='#'>" Add to cart "</a></td>";

Tags: php, html-table, syntax-error, href

```
echo "<td> <a href='#'>" Add to cart "</a></td>";
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\merchant e link\index1.php on line 30

Comment: HINT: Check your quotes and how you are building/concatenating that string.

Comment: plese send the correct code

Comment: Syntax error questions are almost **NEVER** useful for this community. -1 and flag to close

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when retrieving value from database and applying to anchor tag.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289720/error-when-retrieving-value-from-database-and-applying-to-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "<td> <a href='#'> Add to cart </a></td>";
```